# cut from stream witing for EOL/EOF char

Tags: bash, cut

I need to cut something from stream, but it seems, that cut cant process last line before EOL or EOF appear.

My bash command:

```
tail -n 5 -F /data/apache/log/error/error-log | cut -d ' ' -f1-5
```

log file contains for example:

```
[Wed Jan 14 09:00:00 2015] [error] Error 1
[Wed Jan 14 09:10:00 2015] [error] Error 2
[Wed Jan 14 09:20:00 2015] [error] Error 3
[Wed Jan 14 09:30:00 2015] [error] Error 4
[Wed Jan 14 09:40:00 2015] [error] Error 5
```

but my output is:

```
[Wed Jan 14 09:00:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:10:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:20:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:30:00 2015]
```

is there a way to make cut process (and output) last, unfinished line if there are all needed columns (first five) streamed already?

My desired output should contain last line from stream:

```
[Wed Jan 14 09:00:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:10:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:20:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:30:00 2015]
[Wed Jan 14 09:40:00 2015]
```

//edit
Answers "remove -F" are useless, because I need it for live stream. Whenever apache add new entry into log, I need immediately process it with cut. Without user interaction, without running script again etc. Just process stream in real time in the way, that 'cut' don't wait for EOL before it process (and output) line.
If that is not possible, fine, I try to find workaround, but please, don't tell me to not use live stream when I need live stream!

Comment: cut is line-based until it sees EOF or EOL it wont start to process the record.  and with `-F` specified it ignores EOF.

Comment: So there is no way to force to process before EOL?

Comment: you have access to the source code, I presume :)

Comment: source code of tail? here http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c :) but I really do not want to rewrite and recompile core util of linux for one simple function in simple script. For now I did it other way and instead processing stream of data, I'm calling tail + cut every 5 second for new data. Not as clean solution, but still better than rewriting tail :D

Comment: "no way to force to process before EOL" => You need to think again.  Even if it has some way to process before EOL, say, using a customized perl script, you need to provide an end of line pattern, for the script to search, in order to know when a complete line (without line break) is available for processing.  You don't want your program to process in the halfway of a line, right?

Comment: If you somehow tell program after processing to ignore anything until EOL... but that's unnecessary too complex for a little script.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after some tests, I found that the problem is not the `tail` but the `cut`.  Replacing `cut` by `awk` fixes the problem:

```
tail -n 5 -F /data/apache/log/error/error-log | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

Comment: there is no need to say `-F" "` as it is the default settings. Also, `print $1" "$2" "...` is the same as `print $1, $2, ...` because when you place a comma, the default output field separator (OFS) is placed.

Comment: @fedorqui: Thanks for that.  I knew that long ago.  Yet I did not use awk as frequently, and just want to answer this quickly and correctly.  Those redundancy are for safety. ... :-)

Comment: Well, while it is always good to be in the safe side, it is also good to avoid being redundant. I made myself an edit, feel free to revoke if you think it is decreasing the quality. To me, it looks more correct.

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary `-F` (follow & retry) option?
Remove it, and it'll work.

Comment: it is necessary. As I said, I need it for stream - real time reading log.

Comment: I don't know how `tail` is implemented to output data as file grows, but as far as I know, I'm afraid you can't do it using `tail`. Think a process that reads that file every X secs or mins, using `wait` and `sleep`, or a `cron` task.